# How to calculate the spatial elevation angle (depression or looking up) to look up the antenna gain of theta and phi?

Tags: python, geometry, angle

Ok so this is a relatively complex problem:
Imagine the following situation:

- UAV-Coordinates are: (50, 50, 80) (x,y,z in metres)
- Basestation Coordinates are: (50, 100, 80) (x,y,z in metres)

Both, the UAV and the base station are fitted with an antenna that has a directivity. The UAV's antenna is looking straight north (to the BS) and the BS's antenna is looking south (to the UAV in this case).

When I now move the UAV to the Basestation, the depression angle is getting higher and higher until the drone is overtaking the basestation.

My data for the antenna gains (for both antennas) is given in the following CSV format:

HOR_ANGLE; HOR_GAIN; VERT_ANGLE; VERT_GAIN

The angles are in range of zero to 359 degrees and each angle has a corresponding gain value.

My problem is that I need to get the gain of both antennas for the respective angles of directivity (azimuth) and elevation/depression. The antenna diagram is looking in the following way: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkGJf.png) You can see that it is not symmetrical. To obtain the horizontal angle is not a problem, I calculated it the following way:

```
dx = object2[0] - object1[0]
dy = object2[1] - object1[1]
angle_radians = math.atan2(dy, dx)
angle_degree = math.degrees(angle_radians)
angle = angle_degree - 90
if angle < 0:
    angle = abs(angle)
else: 
    angle = 360 - angle
angle = angle - start
if angle < 0:
    angle = 360 + angle
```

Where object 1 or object 2 is either the drone or the base station and Index 0 is the longitude in metres and Index 1 is the latitude in metres. The start is the horizontal angle of the main beam of the antenna.

The problem now occurs when calculating the vertical angle. Because the Pythagorean theorem (calculating the angle with arcus cosine or arcus sine respectively) is not intelligent, it always maps the vertical angle into an interval of -90 to 90 degrees. But I need the angle in the interval of 0 to 359 to get the gain out of the CSV. As you can see in the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkGJf.png) on the right side, there occurs the mapping. The left red dot is theoretically behind the base station so the angle should be (roundabout) 110 degrees. When using the Pythagorean theorem the angle is 70 degrees, which is wrong. This is what I mean with mapping.

When I now implement a restriction for the calculation of the vertical angle in the following way:

```
if 90 < hor_angle < 270:
    vert_angle = vert_angle + 180
```

I now have the problem of a very "hard" border of the horizontal angles as one can see in this picture: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1vIQ.png) This picture shows the UAV from the top (up is north). You can see the directivity of the antenna heading north. Now, because of my implemented restriction, every pixel (or base station) being behind the drone has a very weak antenna gain. In the real world, the "cut" of those values is more dynamic and not so harsh. The following picture shows a 3D diagram of an antenna pattern: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNn7t.png)

I already tried to map the vertical angle to a range of 90 and -90 degrees respective to the horizontal angle but that did not solve the problem.

To put it in a nutshell my question is: How can I calculate the vertical depression or elevation angle (where 0 degree is right and the angles range from 0 to 359 degrees clockwise) with respect to the horizontal angle of the objects dynamically (both for the UAV's and base station's antenna)?

I hope the problem is expressed in an understandable way. I am looking forward to hearing your ideas and follow-up questions or remarks.